# How to get Hours and Minutes from given two dates using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to find the hours and minutes from a given column date to the current date using MYSQL

```
**Agent_Id**  **Date**
9         2020-08-14 04:26:59
24        2020-07-03 08:30:34
80        2020-12-10 03:25:26
111       2020-10-15 04:52:25
117       2020-08-13 10:25:50
135       2020-12-14 03:09:41
```

**table definition for reproducibility**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Agent(Agent_Id INTEGER, Date DATETIME);
DELETE FROM Agent;
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(9,         "2020-08-14 04:26:59");
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(24,        "2020-07-03 08:30:34");
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(80,        "2020-12-10 03:25:26");
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(111,       "2020-10-15 04:52:25");
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(117,       "2020-08-13 10:25:50");
INSERT INTO Agent VALUES(135,       "2020-12-14 03:09:41");
```

**expected output:**

```
**Agent_Id**  **Date**           **HH and Mins**
9             2020-12-14 04:26:59  24 hours, 52 mins
24            2020-12-03 08:30:34  312 hours,40 mins
80            2020-12-10 03:25:26  hh hours, mm mins
111           2020-10-15 04:52:25  hh hours, mm mins
117           2020-08-13 10:25:50  hh hours, mm mins
135           2020-12-14 03:09:41  hh hours, mm mins
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can find plenty of examples here in SO about how to subtract datetime values and get the result as hours / minutes. To get the current datetime you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Or NOW(), if less typing is your thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Now()` to get current time, and then use `TIMEDIFF` to get the difference. Assuming your table name is `Agent`, here's how you get the time difference to now:

```
SELECT Agent_Id,Date,TIMEDIFF(NOW(),Date) FROM Agent;
```

If you want it to be formatted like in your question, use TIME_FORMAT() to format it:

```
SELECT Agent_Id,Date,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),Date),"%H hours, %i minutes")  AS "HH and mins" FROM Agent;
```